# Authentication with Active Directory using sAMAccountName and password / NodeJs

Tags: node.js, authentication, active-directory

I m trying to authenticate to a server with Active Directory using Nodejs. I read a lot a of answers of that but no body use the sAMAccountName as attribute to do that.

My code is :

```
let ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
let config = {
              url: 'ldap://XX.XX.XX.XXX:389',
              baseDN: 'DC=domain,DC=com',
              username: 'serverUserName',
              password: 'serverPsw'
             };

let ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);

let username = 'sAMAccountName=11111111111, OU=Usuarios, DC=domain,DC=com',
    password = 'myPassword';

ad.authenticate(username, password, function (err, auth) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    return;
  }

  if (auth) {
    console.log('\nAuthenticated!', auth);
  }
  else {
    console.log('\nAuthentication failed!');
  }
});
```

This code only works if a change the username

```
 'CN=myIdentifier,OU=Usuarios,DC=domain,DC=com'
```

and use the CN as attribute.

I really don't have idea what to do but it must work using the sAMAccountName.

Can anybody give me a help of how to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot use the sAMAccountName for `authenticate`. It needs either the `userPrincipalName` (user@domain) or the `distinguishedName` (CN=myIdentifier,OU=Usuarios,DC=domain,DC=com). If you **must** get it to work with sAMAccountname only, then first look up the user with [ad.findUser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory#findUser) and take the `userPrincipalName` property. Use that for `ad.authenticate`

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticate against Active directory LDAP using sAMAccountName if you include the domain too - like company\logonid instead of just login ID. You can also use the full userPrincipalName like logonid@company.ccTLD

With either of those formats, you do not use any of the LDAP syntax components (something= or the ,ou=xyz,dc=abc). You use just the login ID and domain name (in the example above, the legacy style domain name is company and the AD style domain name is company.ccTLD)